# how to keep jupyter kernel alive inside vscode remote container?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-devcontainer

#### Question:

How can I disconnect, then reconnect to a vscode dev container without killing the ipynb kernel within my workspace?

#### Background:

I access my jupyter notebook inside a [vscode dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/develop-cloud/containers) in order to have reproducibility of my project-specific environment.  I connect to the container host machine on my laptop.  Upon re-opening my vscode workspace after reconnecting to the container, my ipynb kernel is dead and all notebook computation must be repeated.

Comment: Add `"shutdownAction": "none"` in `devcontainer.json`. Indicates VS Code should not stop the containers when the related tool window is closed. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `jupyter server` instead.

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1378#issuecomment-1004422673) aout using the 'remote' server to control your kernel lifetime for details.